# Why can't I get an actual value besides the one I initially set

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to make a file reader using tkinter, but upon pressing start convert, rather then using the entry I made, it refuses to take what's in the text box.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import ttk

global filename
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Main menu")
window.geometry("500x500")
dictation_prefrence = "OFF"
filename = "g"
text_color = "BLACK"
background_color = "BLACK"
print_type_prefrence = "NO"


def openreadingwindow():
    global file_name_var
    file_name_var = tk.StringVar()
    
    def getfilename():
        filename = file_name_var.get()
        submitbutton.config(state=DISABLED)
        print(filename)
    filewindow = tk.Tk()
    filewindow.title("unkown")
    filewindow.geometry("400x400")
    file_name_entry = tk.Entry(filewindow,textvariable = file_name_var)
    
    submitbutton = tk.Button(filewindow,text="convert",command=getfilename)
    submitbutton.pack()
    file_name_entry.pack()
    e = Label(filewindow,text = filename).pack()
    print(filename)
    
    def file(file_name,file_format):
        file = open(file_name+file_format, "r")
        counter = 0
        for line in file.readlines():
            counter = counter + 1
            print(line)


def opensettingswindow():
    def toggle_button_func_1():
        global print_type_prefrence
        if toggle_button_1.config('text')[-1] == 'YES':
            toggle_button_1.config(text='NO')
            print_type_prefrence = "NO"
        else:
            toggle_button_1.config(text='YES')
            print_type_prefrence = "YES"
    
    def toggle_button_func_2():
        global dictation_prefrence
        if toggle_button_2.config('text')[-1] == 'ON':
            toggle_button_2.config(text='OFF')
            dictation_prefrence = "OFF"
        else:
                toggle_button_2.config(text='ON')
                dictation_prefrence = "ON"
    
    def text_color_selector_func():
        global text_color
        if text_color == "BLACK":
            text_color_selector_button.config(text='WHITE')
            text_color = "WHITE"
        elif text_color == "WHITE":
            text_color_selector_button.config(text='RED')
            text_color = "RED"
        elif text_color == "RED":
            text_color_selector_button.config(text='BLUE')
            text_color = "BLUE"
        elif text_color == "BLUE":
            text_color_selector_button.config(text='YELLOW')
            text_color = "YELLOW"
        else:
            text_color_selector_button.config(text='BLACK')
            text_color = "BLACK"
    
    def background_color_selector_func():
        global background_color
        if background_color == "BLACK":
            background_color_selector_button.config(text='WHITE')
            background_color= "WHITE"
        elif background_color == "WHITE":
            background_color_selector_button.config(text='RED')
            background_color= "RED"
        elif background_color == "RED":
            background_color_selector_button.config(text='BLUE')
            background_color= "BLUE"
        elif background_color == "BLUE":
            background_color_selector_button.config(text='YELLOW')
            background_color= "YELLOW"
        else:
            background_color_selector_button.config(text='BLACK')
            text_color = "BLACK"
    
    settingswindow = Toplevel(window)
    settingswindow.title("Settings")
    settingswindow.geometry("300x400")
    Label(settingswindow,text ="Show paragraphs one at a time").pack()
    toggle_button_1 = ttk.Button(settingswindow,text=print_type_prefrence, width=10, command=toggle_button_func_1)
    toggle_button_1.pack(pady=5)
    Label(settingswindow,text ="dictation(not yet implemented)").pack()
    toggle_button_2 = ttk.Button(settingswindow,text=dictation_prefrence, width=10, command=toggle_button_func_2)
    toggle_button_2.pack(pady=5)
    Label(settingswindow,text ="text color").pack()
    text_color_selector_button= ttk.Button(settingswindow,text=text_color, width=10, command=text_color_selector_func)
    text_color_selector_button.pack(pady=5)
    Label(settingswindow,text ="text background color").pack()
    background_color_selector_button = ttk.Button(settingswindow,text=background_color, width=10, command=background_color_selector_func)
    background_color_selector_button.pack(pady=5)


button = tk.Button(text="settings⚙️",command=opensettingswindow)
button.pack()
button = tk.Button(text="start convert",command=openreadingwindow)
button.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

The specific area I'm having trouble with is in the function `openreadingwindow`, but I wasn't sure if other lines could be affecting it so included the whole project. I am using replit if that is important.

I was expecting it to return whatever you type.

Comment: Please use spacing and  more indentation (4 spaces for each level) to make your code easier to read

Comment: Right now the master of `tk.StringVar()` is `window` but the `tk.Entry` is inside `filewindow`. That is probably why it doesn't work. To fix it either use `filewindow = tk.Toplevel()` instead of `filewindow = tk.Tk()` or move the `file_name_var = tk.StringVar()` after the `filewindow = tk.Tk()` and add `master=filewindow` inside the `tk.StringVar()`.

Comment: another potential problem is you have multiple `filename` variables. You have the local one inside `getfilename` and the global one.

Comment: Thank you TheLizzard made that change and it worked perfectly